MySQL - Proper key length
I was looking at a table definition query from WordPress and noticed something strange. First of all, the query was this:
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->comments (
    comment_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    comment_post_ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    comment_author tinytext NOT NULL,
    comment_author_email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    comment_author_url varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
    comment_author_IP varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    comment_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    comment_date_gmt datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    comment_content text NOT NULL,
    comment_karma int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
    comment_approved varchar(20) NOT NULL default '1',
    comment_agent varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    comment_type varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'comment',
    comment_parent bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    user_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (comment_ID),
    KEY comment_post_ID (comment_post_ID),
    KEY comment_approved_date_gmt (comment_approved,comment_date_gmt),
    KEY comment_date_gmt (comment_date_gmt),
    KEY comment_parent (comment_parent),
    KEY comment_author_email (comment_author_email(10))
) $charset_collate;

As you see, comment_author_email was defined as varchar(100), but then its key was defined with length of 10 chars. Why is that? Is it to save space, since most emails are around 10-15 chars in length?
In that case, does it mean that - for an email with length of 15 chars - the first 10 chars will be indexed and the remaining 5 chars will be unindexed? Is this how it works? (I'm no DB expert as you have guessed).
Finally, I will be adding a table of my own for a mechanism I'm building, that will need to store email addresses and phone numbers. For the email addresses I'll be using a similar definition. As for the phone, I'm thinking to defined it as varchar(25) just to be on the safe side, but for its index, use a key again with 10 chars in length. What do you think about this planning?


Get rid of comment_; it is clutter that makes things less readable.

"Prefixing" is rarely beneficial - in either speed or space.  That is, don't say
KEY comment_author_email (comment_author_email(10))

simply say
KEY comment_author_email (comment_author_email)


Your 10 out of 15 example:  Yes, it saves 5 characters.  But it hurts speed on all queries that use that index.



Thanks for your reply. As I said, I'm no DB expert, so I'll mark your answer as the correct one to my question, hoping that you are one (expert).

I think I am an expert.  Others may come along and provide more insight into your Question; they may agree or disagree with me.  The "reputation" mechanism tends to chase away those with poor Answers.  Keep the Questions coming.
